# Javascript: pushing an array into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

JS question:
I need to push an array to be an element in another array. I got 2 ways: a plain `push()` and one the same but with spread operator

```
arr.push([newArr]);
 arr.push([...newArr]);
```

(both `arr` and `newArr` are arrays)

What does the spread operator actually accomplishes here?
Observing in the console, in the 2nd example, I get the results I want:

> res[0]
> (3) [1, 2, 3]

So the array I pushed becomes an element in the new array. so far so good.

But in the 1st example, without the spread operator, I get:

> res[0]
> [Array(3)]

> res[0][0]
> (3) [1, 2, 3]

And this is what I don't understand. why, when not using spread, I get what seems to be like... sort of a wrapper... over the array? what does it even mean, when I get [Array(x)] in the console?? is it array within array or...?

so the question is: what is this [Array(x)], why is is there, and why does the spread operator clears it out?

Thank You!

Comment: The spread operator is used to unpack an array and assign its elements into a new array. In this case arr.push([newArr]); pushes the entire newArr array as a single element into the arr array, resulting in arr[0] being the array containing the original newArr array. Also, arr.push([...newArr]); unpacks the newArr array and pushes its elements as separate elements into the arr array, resulting in arr[0] being the original newArr array without any wrapping or nesting

Comment: the first `push` do not copy the `newArr` inside, it just do an addressing copy.

Comment: in the first case `(arr[0][0] === newArr)` is `true`, in the second case  `(arr[0] === newArr)` is `false`. Or in in the first case `arr` is a 3 D array, and in the second case  `arr` is just a 2 D  array.

Answer (score 1):

`arr.push([newArr]);` pushes an **array** with one item `newArr` into `arr`.
`arr.push([...newArr]);` pushes a **shallow copy** of `newArr` into `arr`.

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Consider your array `arr` as a row of lockers.

When you use `arr.push([newArr]);` you're taking that entire array `[newArr]`, and putting the entire thing into the next available locker. If `newArr` contains 3 values (lockers) of its own, all three go into that next, single available locker in `arr` as `newArr`, expanding the arr array to accommodate the site, in this case adding 1 locker.

When you use the spread operator, `arr.push([...newArr]);`, you're taking each of the elements of `newArr` out of `newArr`, and putting each one in turn into the next available locker in the row. If `newArr` has 3 values (lockers) of its own, the first goes into the next available locker in `arr`, the 2nd into the 2nd available locker in `arr`, and the 3rd into the 3rd, expanding the arr array to accommodate the site, in this case adding 3 lockers.

The spread operator essentially flattens the array, whereas push does not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this example

```js
const newArr = [1,2,3];

const a1 = [newArr];
const a2 = [...newArr];

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
```

In the first case, `newArr` becomes the first element of the array `a1`.
In the second case, spread operator takes all the elements of the `newArr` and put them one by one as elements of the array `a2`.
So `a1==[newArr]`, `a2==[newArr[0], newArr[1], newArr[2]]`